# expected primary-expression before ')' token (requires "template" disambiguator)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a piece of code resembling the following (other details omitted for brevity):

```
template <uint First, uint Second, typename T>
struct Thing {
  std::shared_ptr<T> asdf;
  uint get() const { this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); }
};
```

... producing the following error in GCC 7:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  uint get() const { this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); }
                                                         ^
```

Clang 4.0.1 reports no warnings with `-Weverything` (excepting very pedantic things like c++98 compatibility warnings); same thing with GCC 7 and `-W{all,extra,effc++,pedantic}`.

---

I was previously unaware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords); while the answer to my problem is certainly outlined there, the error message didn't make it plain that was the problem.  Supposing I deleted this question and its associated answer, other people searching for this error message will only run across the questions I found -- that is, the ones indicating the problem was caused by passing a type as a function argument instead of passing a value.

Comment: @Rakete1111 According to [this blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @xskxzr Could you expend a bit please? Because the OP needed to put a `template` in there, which is what the dupe answers by explaining why it's needed.

Comment: @Rakete1111 They are two *different* questions with the same answer. I found a discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74080/close-as-duplicate-what-if-only-the-answer-is-a-duplicate). To be honest, I am not very sure whether it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: The solution was to use the `template` keyword as a [disambiguator (at the bottom of the page)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) when calling `get_value<A,B>()`:

```
uint get() const { auto tmp = this->asdf->template get_value<First,Second>(); return tmp; }
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

The other answers I came across related to this error were a result of the code passing a type instead of a value as an argument to the function.

In this case the function takes no arguments.  What made the problem obvious was changing the form of the code, producing better errors:

```
template <uint First, uint Second, typename T>
struct Thing {
  std::shared_ptr<T> asdf;
  uint get() const { auto tmp = this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); return tmp; }
```

... which changed the errors to:

```
error: declaration of 'Second' shadows template parameter
  uint get() const { auto tmp = this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); return tmp; }

error: declaration of 'Second' with type 'auto' requires an initializer
  uint get() const { auto tmp = this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); return tmp; }
                                                            ^
error: expected ';' at end of declaration    };
  uint get() const { auto tmp = this->asdf->get_value<First,Second>(); return tmp; }
                                                                  ^
```